# Android: Show videos in WebView always fullscreen?

Tags: android, webview, html5-video

I have a WebView showing a HTML document with media content (embedded Youtube video, html5 video...). Is it possible to show them only as thumbnail and always open a fullscreen video view when the user clicks on them?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse all content and show only preview picture. When user clicks on it you can start new fullscreen activity and play video there.

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed one option.